# Is the electric flux from the antenna able to exist without connecting electric charge?

Tags: antennas

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_wave#/media/File:Dipole_xmting_antenna_animation_4_408x318x150ms.gif

According to above figure, the electric flux is in the close loop state like a balloon and is pushed out by the other electric flux. So it looks like that electric flux loops pop out from the antenna even though the origin of the magnetic field is still addicted to the antenna.

Is this the result of flux adding and cancellation effect of the positive charge and the negative charge?

(I mean the origin of the electric field is still addicted to the antenna?)

Or the closed flux loops are really popping out from the antenna?